# Fail to assign Xpath value to string

Tags: string

I just tried to assign the value which i got from html page into a string but it failed at the the method Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs

Though I'm new to WP8, please help me to understand the reason and fix it.Thanks everyone.

My code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode imageNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='fck_detail width_common']/table/img[@src]");
string imgUrl = imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Failed at Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs

```
 private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days,i figured out this. Just need to fix the behavior of xml by 1 line before you load the Html document by below code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("img");
```